# Linux Shell: VLC programming

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vlc

Is there a way to manipulate VLC with a Linux shell script without the script waiting for VLC to close.

```
cvlc test.mp3
echo "Now playing!"
sleep 200
cvlc://pause:60
```

This code keeps running VLC until the file is completed, and then evidently it is to late to pause the file.

Comment: Have you tried to run the command in background like `cvlc test.mp3 &`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use dbus interface of VLC.

[image]

Now, you can use the [mpris](http://www.mpris.org/2.1/spec/) interface of VLC. It's a standard for most players like clementine, banshee, songbird, spotify etc.

So, lets suppose you want to Pause the currently playing song.

```
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.vlc /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.Pause
```

To play a song:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.vlc /Player org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.Play
```

I generally use qdbusviewer to know about the dbus-interface available to me.

Comment: Although your solution pointed me in the right direction, current VLC only accepts a slightly different implementation. For example: `dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause`

Comment: Cool. Glad that my answer was of help.

Comment: May be a little late, but, I'll leave it here for reference. This bash script uses gdbus to do various operations with a running instance of vlc, like, get supported mime types, get status, play, pause, get / set volume, list instances, etc.: https://gist.github.com/amol9/6d47fdd21a1c5e006c84

Answer (score 4):

Dbus is one way but dbus does not exist on all systems. The more common method would be to use the rc interface:

`cvlc -I rc --rc-host localhost:11337 -d`

Then one can use netcat to pipe commands into the tcp socket. For example:

```
vlc -I rc --rc-host localhost:11337 test.mp3 -d &
echo "Now playing!"
sleep 200
echo pause | netcat localhost 11337
```

EDIT:

After testing with a few other interfaces I have discovered the `oldrc` interface accepts UNIX domain sockets thus the following will work as well with out needing to play around with firewalls or worry about anyone else on the network messing around with your vlc instance.

```
vlc -I oldrc --rc-unix /var/run/vlc.sock -d
echo "Now Playing!"
sleep 200
echo "pause" | netcat -U /var/run/vlc.sock
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can redirect from standard input or a named pipe.  For more complicated things you could use libvlc.

http://wiki.videolan.org/Uncommon_uses